# Invalid assignment of JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

```
var datas = [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4feeaa97cb675ea1a62cf64a"} , "Amount" : 35.0 , "Category_ID" : "Vegetables"}, { "_id" : { "$oid" : "4feeaaafcb675ea1a62cf64b"} , "Amount" : 55.0 , "Category_ID" : "Vegetables"}]; // these data are from database...
```

i want to assign it as,

```
var obj = {"row": datas};
```

but it doesn't work when i use like,

```
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();         
 data.addColumn('string','Category_ID');
 data.addColumn('number','Amount'); 
 data.addRows([
                   [obj.row[0].Category_ID, obj.row[0].Amount],
               [obj.row[1].Category_ID, obj.row[1].Amount],
               [obj.row[2].Category_ID, obj.row[2].Amount]
             ]);
```

Comment: what's the error message on the console? I guess it will point you to the error pretty well...

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();         
 data.addColumn('string','Category_ID');
 data.addColumn('number','Amount'); 
 data.addRows([
                   [obj.row[0].Category_ID, obj.row[0].Amount],
               [obj.row[1].Category_ID, obj.row[1].Amount]
]);
```

This is because your datas array has only 2 elements but you are trying to access three.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know how many rows you have, you could do it like this:

```
data.addRows(obj.row.map(function(el) {
  return [el.Category_ID, el.Amount];
}));
```